# Using Non-commercial license of ArcGIS for Desktop to undertake Proof of Concept?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, license

in our company we are using QGIS for any GIS related analyses. However I really want my boss to invest in ArcGIS because I believe its a lot more functional and stable than OpenSource solutions.

However I only own a non-commercial version of ArcGIS that I use at home for online courses. I thought about reworking one of our former projects in order to convince my boss of the advantages and make him investing into ArcGIS.

The question: Am I actually allowed to do this with a non-commercial version? I am really careful about anything related to copyright issues, so I thought I better ask beforehand. I do not intend to sell any of the data to anyone.

Comment: You'd be better off asking ESRI directly. I suspect that since you aren't selling the data you'd be fine (especially since you're really doing their marketing for them) but it's their license and they may see things differently.

Comment: Ok, I will send them an email!

Comment: You can use a 60 day trial http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/free-trial as a convincer.

Comment: I thought that the 60 day trial underlies the same regulations as the non-commercial version. I think the best way to find out about this is to ask esri.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best asked directly of the vendor involved.